# How do I change add alt text from another element to my div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the alt text and background image of my div with the id = image, using javascript.

I have tried using `document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = this.alt`     to change the text but it doesn't work.

I have also tried using `document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = this.src`

Can anyone provide me with some insight?

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = this.src;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
  <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
  </div>

  <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

  <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

  <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `this` would refer to the function in that context, not the image. You want `previewPic.alt` or `previewPic.src`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

As @Toastrackenigma mentioned, the javascript keyword `this` in a function only refers to the function context, not the `previewPic` parameter that you're looking for. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You can use `onmouseover="upDate(this)"` in HTML since the `this` keyword in the HTML refers to the image, but the `this` keyword in JS does not.

What you're looking for might be something like this:

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = `url(${previewPic.src})`;
}
```

However, as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11775023/13991219), a background image is only for *decoration* and shouldn't have any *semantic meaning*, so it shouldn't have an `alt` attribute. You might be considering a [`title`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute for the `div` element, which would display a small tooltip on hover. Likewise, you would use

```js
document.getElementById('image').title = previewPic.alt;
```